# Using Xcode 4.x to open .class (java compiled) files

Tags: java, xcode, .class-file

I used to use Xcode 3 to open compiled java files. It automatically decompiled it. This way, I was able to read the name of the methods that where available in a .class file.

However, since I updated to Xcode 4, I am unable to do it. Xcode is no longer configured to launch .class files in Finder and if I try to select it it just shows a giant icon.

Is there a way to do this? If there is not, what's the best workaround solution?